# Showing/hiding an element on display resize in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, reactstrap

```
      <React.Fragment>
        <Jumbotron fluid className="mb-0">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <h1>
                  MFICC <i className="fa fa-moon-o fa-1x" />
                </h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Jumbotron>
        <Navbar dark sticky="top" expand="md">
          <div className="container">
            <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNav} />
            <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isNavOpen} navbar>
              <Nav navbar>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/">
                    <i className="fa fa-home fa-lg" /> Home
                  </NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/videos">
                    <i className="fa fa-video-camera fa-lg" /> Videos
                  </NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/questions">
                    <i className="fa fa-question fa-lg" /> Questions
                  </NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/updates">
                    <i className="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-lg" /> Updates
                  </NavLink>
                </NavItem>
                  <NavItem>
                    <NavLink
                      className="nav-link"
                      to="https://www.gofundme.com/f/moorhead-mosque-foundation"
                    >
                      <Button variant="primary">Donate</Button>
                    </NavLink>
                  </NavItem>

              </Nav>
            </Collapse>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
      </React.Fragment>
```

My goal is to show the nav (Donate) button which is the last nav item. When the display width is less than 844px I want to show it and hide it when it reaches 845px and up. How can I go about doing that?.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried playing with the window media object but that wasn't working but got it solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a in your Css part:

```
@media (min-width: 844px){
.elementToHide{ 
   display: none;
   } 
}
```

It's a lot easier and less expensive than checking for window size and conditionally render elements.

Comment: Relateable haha